# Fast Points in polygon count PostGIS

Tags: polygon, postgis, point, intersect, lateral-join

I am having speed issues building a simple ***points within buffer*** query, ie.
counting the number of points inside a buffer given a centroid and a buffer distance.

I have `<100` centroids (buffers) and `250.000` points.

Both tables have indexes and have been vaccum-analyzed beforehand.

I have been trying several things and none seems to be working effciently.

```
SELECT parcels.id, count(*) AS totale
FROM
    _BUFFERS  parcels,
    _POINTS ints
WHERE 
    AND ST_intersects( ST_Buffer(parcels.centroid::geography, 800), ints.geom)
GROUP BY parcels.id;
```

Also tried `LATERAL` joins with no success:

```
SELECT r.id, r.pcount FROM
    (SELECT
        id, ST_Buffer(centroid::geography, 800) as the_geom
     FROM
        _BUFFERS ) n,
    LATERAL (
        SELECT
            n.id, count(*) as pcount
        FROM
            _POINTS p
        WHERE
            n.the_geom && geom
    ) r
```

I must be doing something completely wrong here??
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are both your "geom" columns geometry or geography types? Make sure they are the same... If you are using geometry, make sure the SRID is in the units you expect (e.g. metres)

I don't think you need to create the buffer, you can just use [st_dwithin](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html).

I.e.

```
SELECT parcels.id, count(*) AS totale
FROM
 _BUFFERS  parcels
INNER JOIN
    _POINTS ints
on st_dwithin(parcels.centroid, ints.geom,800)
GROUP BY parcels.id;
```

Note that if a point is within your distance of more than one centroid, it will get double-counted.

Comment: They are both geometry `geom geometry(Point,4326)` and `centroid geometry(Point,4326)`. So it should be `ST_DWITHIN(parcels.centroid::geography, ints.geom::geography, 800)`, which still takes over 2 minutes to run (better than before, but still quite long?)

Comment: Thing is, that creates a lot of work in converting to geography and I doubt the query will use any indexes that you've got on the geometries. You could put an index on geom::geography, but unless you have a good reason for using geometry in 4326 I'd either convert the columns to geography (and re-index) or change the SRID to something in metres...

Comment: fantastic!! Following your suggestion I created two geometry columns transforming the `4326` to my local `srid` and the calculation took less than a second. Thanks a lot!